# Are there VPN providers accepting monero?

Tags: vpn

Bitcoin is pretty widely accepted to purchase VPN services. I'm curious if monero is accepted by anyone yet.

Comment: here you can find 11 VPN services accepting Monero as a payment https://cryptwerk.com/companies/vpn/xmr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cryptostorm](https://cryptostorm.org/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=6380&p=10266&hilit=monero#p10266) accepts Monero directly. Some community feedback for the VPN can be found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4rbchx/big_up_to_vpn_provider_cryptostormis/).

Any Bitcoin accepting VPN can be paid with [xmr.to or shapeshift](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-i-use-monero-to-pay-a-bitcoin-accepting-merchant)

Comment: Oh good point. Shapeshift would accomplish that.

Comment: Cryptostorm doesn't appear to support Monero directly anymore. I decided to check out xmr.to for the first time. Once my blockchain syncs, I'll give that a try.

Cryptostorm has better prices than IVPN as well. Good to shop around.

Answer (score 3):

There's another one!
http://cloakvpn.com/monero

I like how they handle creating accounts:

> A 30-day account will be provisioned for you using th 16 character Payment_ID you provide.
>   UserName = The first 12 characters of your Payment_ID.
>   Password = The 13-16th characters of your Payment_ID. (last 4 digits)

Announcement [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6cpfd2/cloakvpncom_now_accepts_monero_using_payment_id/)

Disclaimer: this is not an endorsement, but I do like how it's set up. Don't know about quality of the actaul service provided, as I haven't yet tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

[BolehVPN](https://www.bolehvpn.net/paywithcrypto/) also supports XMR (through Coinpayments)

> To support the use of anonymous currencies, services purchased using Dash, Monero, Zcoin and Zcash enjoy a 10% discount off the listed price.
>
> You can either pay using Coinpayments which processes the conversion automatically or if you’re paying via Dash directly,

**NOTE:** I have never used them and this is **not an endorsement**.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, [Mullvad](https://mullvad.net/en/pricing/) and [IVPN](https://www.ivpn.net/pricing/) note that they accept Monero. As a bonus, as of 2021, both of these were also noted as [not having any detected trackers](https://themarkup.org/the-breakdown/2021/08/12/how-private-is-my-vpn).

Answer (score 0):

See [Monero VPN for Chrome](https://getmonerovpn.com), its completely anonymous, free for life, and mines Monero to pay for the service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of 32 VPN services accepting Monero

https://cryptwerk.com/companies/vpn/xmr/